# CMake linker error with SSL libraries

Tags: cmake

I am compiling & linking the OPC UA source code in Linux which is using CMake to build binaries.
While linking, I got the below error:

```
/bin/linux/xxx/Debug/libxx.so: undefined reference to
`CRYPTO_free@OPENSSL_1.0.0' /bin/linux/xxx/Debug/libxx.so: undefined
reference to `i2d_X509@OPENSSL_1.0.0'
```

it is refering SSL, crypto libraries which are present in the custom library (/opt/lib/) path.

To resolve this error, I tried

1)I added the /opt/lib in linker flags also:

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-L/opt/lib/ -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lrt ")

add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})

SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
```

2)I also added ssl and crypto library path in link_directories:

```
set (OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS /opt/lib)

link_directories(${OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Still I am getting the same linker problem.

Under `/opt/lib/`, `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so` are available.
I was able to successfully compile link and run the sample Qt project which is using `CRYPTO_free()` function by adding ssl and crypto libraries.
But I would like to know how to make it work with CMake.

Note: I am using cmake version 3.3.0-rc3 version.

Comment: Don't add linker flags like that — CMake is not GNU Make, use the [appropriate](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/find_library.html) [commands](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_link_libraries.html) instead. Set the `VERBOSE=1` environment variable when running `make` and inspect the command line. If something isn't right, adjust your CMake file accordingly. Your current question is very vague and it is hard to give more specific advice without knowing additional details.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Finally I solved this problem by adding SSL library path to CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH. [Actually we are having customized buildroot on which SSL libraries are present.]  After this find_package() is able to identify the SSL installation.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you should use `find_package(OpenSSL)` and use the resulting OPENSSL_... variables instead of hard coding the library names and search paths. You can set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR before calling `find_package` to tell the module where to search for OpenSSL.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenSSL.html

If you are cross compiling for another target, you should try using a toolchain file to tell CMake where to look for includes and libraries in general.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html